# How to enable SqlDependency OnChange event to handle multiple requests at a time

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldependency

When we work with `SqlDependency`, then we work with `OnDataChange` event and this event notifies us regarding a data change in a table. Suppose my application is monitoring a `test` table using `SqlDependency`, and suppose huge amounts of data is getting inserted and updated in the `test` table very frequently. I do not know how SqlDependency's `OnDataChange` event can handle this situation because `OnDataChange` event will fire as often as data changes in the db table.

Here is a snippet of my code for the `OnChange` event:

```
void OnDataChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    ((SqlDependency)sender).OnChange -= OnDataChange;

    BBALogger.Write("PartIndexer Service RegisterNotification called end", BBALogger.MsgType.Info);

    if (e.Source == SqlNotificationSource.Timeout)
    {
        MailSend(); // notification mail send
        BBALogger.Write("PartIndexer Service SqlNotificationSource.Timeout error", BBALogger.MsgType.Error);

        Environment.Exit(1);
    }
    else if (e.Source != SqlNotificationSource.Data)
    {
        MailSend(); // notification mail send
        BBALogger.Write("PartIndexer Service SqlNotificationSource.Data", BBALogger.MsgType.Error);

        Environment.Exit(1);
    }
    else if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
    {
        StartIndex();
        BBALogger.Write("PartIndexer Service Data changed", BBALogger.MsgType.Info);
    }
    else
    {
        BBALogger.Write(string.Format("Ignored change notification {0}/{1} ({2})", e.Type, e.Info, e.Source), BBALogger.MsgType.Warnings);
    }

    RegisterNotification();
}
```

I'm looking for some help in designing my `OnDataChange` event in such a way that if data is changed *very frequently* in the `test` table, then `OnDataChange` can handle the situation. The `OnDataChange` event should not freeze and should log each data change in xml file.

Comment: I'm not sure if `SqlDependency` is something that would work for your situation. Maybe you could try [Change Data Capture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933994(v=sql.110).aspx)?

Comment: @jjj Chage data capture can not notify winform client like sql dependency. thanks